# onSnapchatPageHide and onSnapchatPageShow errors

Tags: snapchat

We are getting `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onSnapchatPageShow` on pages opened in the snapchat app. What is the issue, should we add a library to our page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug on snapchat SDK which didn't affect user experience. It is fixed now.